# Java stored procedure with mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Can you help me: I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using jdbc but I keep getting an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index of 2 is out of range (1, 1)

Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `count_product`(IN p_id INT)

BEGIN
select firstname  FROM product WHERE id=p_id;
END $$
```

Code:

```
public class StoredProcedure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection con=null;

        java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Id(int):");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personsdb","root","");

            System.out.println("Connected");
            stmt = con.prepareCall("{call count_product(?,?)}");

            System.out.println("called");
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

            stmt.execute();

            String firstname = stmt.getString(2);

            if(firstname != null) {
                System.out.println("First Name=" + firstname);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Result Not Found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: your SP signature has only only one parameter of type `IN` and no `OUT` param is declared.

Comment: `stmt.getString(2);` is the culprit.

Comment: @Tirath: No. Error is at `registerOutParamter`

Comment: @Ravinder Stored procedures are not my cup of tea. I think his code will still not work even after correcting the SP because of what I have pointed out. Correct me if I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined any `OUT` parameter in your SP signature. Unless which, it throws an error while registering an `OUT` parameter from client program.

Change your SP signature as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
       PROCEDURE `count_product`(IN p_id INT, OUT out_param varchar)
```

But, in your procedure you are just selecting a set of records but not doing any other operation to find and set an `OUT` parameter. So, there won't be any need of such `OUT` parameter. Instead read the resultset after executing statement and loop through to find what you want.